# North-West Coordinate dependent on margin?

Tags: tikz-pgf, header-footer, fancyhdr, coordinates

I have the following code (The documentclass is taken from [here](http://www.latextemplates.com/template/masters-doctoral-thesis)):

```
\documentclass{Thesis}
\usepackage{tikz}
\definecolor{RoyalRed}{RGB}{157,16,45}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand\headrulewidth{0pt}
\fancyhead[LE]
{\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\fill[green] ([xshift=1.5cm]current page.north west) rectangle (\paperwidth,1cm);%
\fill[red] (current page.north west) rectangle (0cm,1cm);%
\node[anchor=west] at (0,1.5cm) {\bfseries \color{black}{\leftmark}};
\node[anchor=west] at ([yshift=-0.608cm]current page.north west) {\bfseries \color{black}{Page \thepage}};
 \end{tikzpicture}
}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Test Chapter}
\section{Test Section}    
\lipsum[1-4]
\end{document}
```

Where I want to have a ribbon in the header that goes from one corner of the page (the one on the top left) to the end of the page, at an offset of 1 cm. It used to work perfectly fine until I replaced MikTex with Tex Live. Now it looks like this:

[image]

Instead of going all the way up, it has a white space between the page margin and the ribbon. Also, is the "north west" option dependent on the margin or it should go to the 0,0 coordinate of the page regardless of the geometry?

Edit: The code for the Thesis.cls can be found here: http://pastebin.com/UJjpkysu

Anyone, any suggestion?

Comment: When I try your code with that class I get an error saying that `fancyhdr` is incompatible with the class. It works fine with e.g. `book`.

Comment: Darn! Do you know what would be the cause? Maybe it's a package issue, since everything started to go wrong when I installed Tex Live... What if you disable this: %\usepackage{fancyhdr}

%\lhead[\rm\thepage]{\fancyplain{}{\sl{\rightmark}}}
%\rhead[\fancyplain{}{\sl{\leftmark}}]{\rm\thepage}
%\chead{}\lfoot{}\rfoot{}\cfoot{}

%\pagestyle{fancy} in the .cls file?

Comment: There is no such code in the `.cls` file, looks like it's using `scrlayer-scrpage` instead of `fancyhdr`. If you got the class from that site originally, they have modified it since.

Comment: Damn. It would be too much to add my .cls file... Do you have any idea what would be the cause of that shift? Is there something else that would reset the coordinate for "north west"?

Comment: You can try removing as much as possible from the `.cls` file and posting the reduced version. As long as you have remembered to compile the document twice I don't know what could cause the problem.

Comment: I still can't do it. Do you think this code is responsible for this? \setmarginsrb  { 1.5in}  % left margin
                        { 0.6in}  % top margin
                        { 1.0in}  % right margin
                        { 0.8in}  % bottom margin
                        {  20pt}  % head height
                        {0.25in}  % head sep
                        {   9pt}  % foot height
                        { 0.3in}  % foot sep
If I disable it it makes no changes though, which is suspicious

Comment: If you disable it and it doesn't make a difference, then there is no reason to suspect it's the culprit, is it? Can you post the `.cls` file on Pastebin or something then?

Comment: Okay. I am not sure if I'm doing correctly. The link to the Pastebin is: http://pastebin.com/UJjpkysu . Can you see it?

Comment: Yes, and I can reproduce the problem at least, which is a start.

Comment: The `vmargin` package seems to be the cause of the problem, try removing that and the `\setmarginsrb` block.

Comment: Okay. It worked! Thank you very much. This also answers the last question I had... north west condition depends on the margin and not on the origin of page, as if it would have been (x=0,y=0)... Weird!

Comment: `vmargin` is known to be problematic. Don't use a class which uses `vmargin`.

Comment: That's not the only reason I wouldn't use this class. I have several before I've got to line 60. The mess here WILL cause problems where you least expect them and when you least need them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer to this question is probably: use a different class. Or at least use the most up to date version. If you do that you'll probably need to figure out how to use `scrlayer-scrpage` to set the headers.  (That class has [a bit of a history](https://github.com/johannesbottcher/templateConfusion/blob/master/ourFamousThesisTemplate.md) by the way. Be careful about speaking to Johannes_B about it though, he may suffer a heart attack.)

That said, the specific culprit in your version of the class is the `vmargin` package, which is an old package for setting margins, and is known to be problematic. Normally you'd be better off with using the `geometry` package for modifying margins and page sizes. Exactly what `vmargin` does that interferes with TikZ's pagenodes I don't know, but the easiest fix is to remove that package and the `\setmarginsrb` block.

Comment: (+1) For the medical warnings, just for a start ;).